# Printing highest average - "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'"

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I'm trying to achieve an output of the average score printed from highest to lowest. However, when I run the program, I get an error: `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`.

I'm fairly new to Python and I don't know where I went wrong with this code:

```
f = open('ClassA.txt', 'r')
#a empty dictionar created
d = {}
#loop to split the data in the ext file
for line in f:
    columns = line.split(": ")
    #identifies the key and value with either 0 or 1
    names = columns[0]
    scores = columns[1].strip()
    #appends values if a key already exists
    tries = 0
    while tries < 3:
        d.setdefault(names, []).append(scores)
        tries = tries + 1
if wish == '3':
    for names, v in sorted(d.items()):
        average = sum(v)/len(v)
        print ("{} Scored: {}".format(names,average))
```

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\task 3 final.py", line 33, in <module>
    average = sum(v)/len(v) 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Which line is giving this error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\task 3 final.py", line 33, in <module>
    average = sum(v)/len(v)

Comment: @PythonPerson: you should [edit] your question to add that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *strings* in your dictionary, but `sum()` will start with the number `0` to sum numeric values only:

```
>>> sum(['1', '2'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Convert your scores to numbers, either `int()` or `float()` depending on your format:

```
scores = int(columns[1].strip())
```

Comment: Solved it but I run into another error. When i `print ("{} Scored: {}".format(names,max(average)))` it comes up with `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable` even if i do `float(scores)`

Comment: @PythonPerson: `average` is not a sequence, it is *one float number*. If you wanted to find the maximum across more than one such number, you'll have to keep track of those in a list for example.

Comment: is there a function which would enable me to print from highest to lowest or do i have to create a loop to do so ?

Comment: @PythonPerson: you already have a loop, but you need to collect your averages in a list, and print *after the loop is done* to pick a highest value from the ones you collected in the list.

Comment: i did averages = [average] then printed `max(averages)` it allows me to do so but it doesnt go from highest to lowest ;/

Comment: @PythonPerson: no, because you only have **one average**. Put the list *outside* your loop. `averages = []`. Then **add averages to that list**. `average.append(average)`. Now you have more than one value.